# Use FlexboxLayout programmatically

Tags: android, flexbox, android-flexboxlayout

I'm facing some problems trying to create a simple interface using [FlexboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout).
I create the view in .xml file and all works as expected, but when I try to create the same view programmatically, I'm not be able to set the `layout_flexBasisPercent`.
I'm trying to achive something like this:
[image]

Here it is the xml code:

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:flexDirection="row"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:flexDirection="row"
        app:layout_flexBasisPercent="30%"
        app:layout_order="2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/lorem"/>

    </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>

    <com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:flexDirection="row"
        app:layout_flexBasisPercent="70%"
        app:layout_order="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/random"/>

    </com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

And I'm trying to reproduce the same view programmatically with this code, but doesn't work:

```
    FlexboxLayout fb = findViewById(R.id.fb_main);
    fb.setLayoutDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);

    // Create right subregion on main layout
    FlexboxLayout right = new FlexboxLayout(this);
    FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams lpRight =
            new FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams(
                    FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    lpRight.setFlexBasisPercent(30f);
    lpRight.setOrder(2);
    lpRight.setLayoutDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
    // Right subregions contains a Textview
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setLayoutParams(lpRight);
    tv.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.lorem));
    right.addView(tv);

    // Create left subregion on main layout
    FlexboxLayout left = new FlexboxLayout(this);
    FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams lpLeft =
            new FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams(
                    FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    lpLeft.setFlexBasisPercent(70f);
    lpLeft.setOrder(1);
    lpLeft.setLayoutDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
    // Left subregion contains an Imageview
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setLayoutParams(lpLeft);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.random);
    iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    left.addView(iv);

    fb.addView(left);
    fb.addView(right);
```

Can anyone find the error ? Or what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to specifically use `FlexboxLayout`? From your posted "desired" image, this looks like something you could do with just a `LinearLayout`

Comment: Hi @BenP.  ! Yes, I need to use FlexboxLayout. I have to create more complex views, but I have to start with an easiest one like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading through your code is somewhat difficult; I recommend refactoring it into smaller methods to make reasoning about things easier. That being said, I see some problems:

> ```
> fb.setLayoutDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
> ```

This should be a call to `fb.setFlexDirection()` instead.

> ```
> FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams lpRight =
>         new FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams(
>                 FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
>                 FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
> lpRight.setFlexBasisPercent(30f);
> lpRight.setOrder(2);
> lpRight.setLayoutDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
> // Right subregions contains a Textview
> TextView tv = new TextView(this);
> tv.setLayoutParams(lpRight);
> ```

Here you are creating a `LayoutParams` object with the flex basis and order values that you originally had on your "right" child `FlexboxLayout`, but you're then setting these `LayoutParams` to the `TextView` instead.

Additionally, you are accidentally calling `setLayoutDirection()` instead of `setFlexDirection()` again.

> ```
> FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams lpLeft =
>         new FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams(
>                 FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
>                 FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
> lpLeft.setFlexBasisPercent(70f);
> lpLeft.setOrder(1);
> lpLeft.setLayoutDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
> // Left subregion contains an Imageview
> ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
> iv.setLayoutParams(lpLeft);
> ```

Same problem here.

Here's a working activity that does what you posted in your image:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FlexboxLayout root = createRootView();
        setContentView(root);

        FlexboxLayout right = createRightFlexbox();
        TextView rightText = createTextView();
        right.addView(rightText);
        root.addView(right);

        FlexboxLayout left = createLeftFlexbox();
        ImageView leftImage = createImageView();
        left.addView(leftImage);
        root.addView(left);
    }

    private FlexboxLayout createRootView() {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT);

        FlexboxLayout flexbox = new FlexboxLayout(this);
        flexbox.setLayoutParams(params);
        flexbox.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);

        return flexbox;
    }

    private FlexboxLayout createRightFlexbox() {
        FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams params = new FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setFlexBasisPercent(0.3f);
        params.setOrder(2);

        FlexboxLayout flexbox = new FlexboxLayout(this);
        flexbox.setLayoutParams(params);
        flexbox.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);

        return flexbox;
    }

    private TextView createTextView() {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);
        textView.setText(R.string.lorem);

        return textView;
    }

    private FlexboxLayout createLeftFlexbox() {
        FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams params = new FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setFlexBasisPercent(0.7f);
        params.setOrder(1);

        FlexboxLayout flexbox = new FlexboxLayout(this);
        flexbox.setLayoutParams(params);
        flexbox.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);

        return flexbox;
    }

    private ImageView createImageView() {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.random);

        return imageView;
    }
}
```

By splitting the code into methods, it becomes a lot easier to see which layout params you're applying to which views. Plus you get to see the overall structure of the screen at the top level.

Comment: Thank you so much @BenP. !  Obviously my code was a mess and I think that set the flex basis value to "60" instead of "0.6" was the main problem here. Again, thank you.